# How to write Compose Test cases to check lottie file loaded or not in android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to write Compose Test case to validate correct lottie file played or not in Android with Jetpack Compose?

```
class SampleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                Animation()
            }
        }
    }

}


@Composable
fun Animation() {
  //Lottie animation code

}
```

Comment: did u find something?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the LottieComposition docs. Seems to be what you're looking for.

Docs: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie/blob/master/android-compose.md#lottiecomposition

```kotlin
val compositionResult: LottieCompositionResult = rememberLottieComposition(spec)
```

`LottieCompositionResult` lets you:

1. Access the composition via `compositionResult.value`
2. Access `error`, `isLoading`, `isComplete`, `isFailure`, and `isSuccess` properties.
3. Call `await()` to await the parsed composition from a coroutine.

Comment: I know how to play lottie file with compose. I want to write instrument test cases to validate